# I want to perform API testing using google search.

Tags: web-api-testing

I want to perform API testing using google search. Enter the text in google.com and from the results, search the Wikipedia link and navigate to the wikipedia link. Please suggest how to do perform this using java Selenium using Rest Assured API

Answer (score 0):

You have to read and try by yourself before asking. It seems you didn't tried anything at all, you have no clu how to start. So I give you a hand:

```
package navi;

import java.awt.AWTException;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class Google2Wiki {

    // defines driver
    private static WebDriver driver;

    // new wait for 5 seconds
    WebDriverWait wait5s = new WebDriverWait(driver,5);

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
        // path to chromedriver.exe
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        // new ChromeOptions instance
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        // optionaly an existing browser profile can be used instead of a temporary profile
        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pburgr\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data");
        // new ChromerDriver instance with oprtions
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        // maximizes current window
        driver.manage().window().maximize();}   
    @Before
    public void setUp() {}
    @After
    public void tearDown() {}
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {driver.close();driver.quit();}
    @Test
    public void autofill_first_value () throws InterruptedException, AWTException {

        // get Google.com
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        // wait up to 5 seconds for input field
        WebElement fld_search = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lst-ib")));

        // enterring text to search
        fld_search.click();
        fld_search.sendKeys("french military victories wiki");

        // hitting the search button
        WebElement btn_search = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));
        btn_search.click();

        // get the first link as WebElement
        WebElement first_link = wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rso\"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/h3/a")));
        first_link.click();

        // try to wait up to 5 seconds until reaching wiki
        try {wait5s.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains("wikipedia.org"));} catch (TimeoutException e) {}
    }
}
```